# Список файлов в директории, которые содержат искомое слово

Tags: php

Чего то здесь не хватает мне для результата, но не ясно чего. Выдаёт ошибку в строке **result[]=$arr[$i];**

```
function search_dir($dir, $word){
        $arr=(scandir($dir));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            $pos=strpos($arr[$i],$word);
            if($pos!==false){
                $result[]=$arr[$i];
            }
        }return $result;
    }
    print_r(search_dir(__DIR__,'name'));
```

Comment: а что за ошибку выдает вы принципиально не скажите?

Comment: undefined variable $result. Пытался её инициализировать в функции, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: каким образом и где вы пытались её инициализировать, покажите?

Comment: Перед строкой $arr=(scandir($dir)); писал $result = array(" ");

Comment: Сдается мне ошибка у вас не там... ибо так работать должно...может отладчиком пройдетесь?

Comment: Алексей, не там что?

Comment: Сдается мне **ОШИБКА** у вас не там

Comment: пишет что непроинициализирована переменная result. Я поставил die ("всё ок"); перед строкой $result[]=$arr[$i]; и вывело всё ок. Так что по ходу надо как-то определить переменную..не понятно как.

Comment: @Sven `Перед строкой $arr=(scandir($dir)); писал $result = array(" ");` что-то по коду не видно, чтобы Вы это писали

Comment: я вот понять чего не могу, а что мешает использовать glob? `$result = glob($dir.'/*'.$word.'*');`

Comment: Но выводит лишь Array()

Comment: В целом, если проинициализировать переменную result, то выведет просто Array() и всё. Скрипт не отрабатывает на вывод списка файлов при определённом искомым словом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить `$result = array();`

```
function search_dir($dir, $word)
{
    $result = array();
    $arr = (scandir($dir));
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if (('.' != $arr[$i]) && ('..' != $arr[$i])) {
            $filename = $dir . $arr[$i]; // Возможно, $dir . '/' . $arr[$i]
            if(is_file($filename)){
                $x = file_get_contents($dir . $arr[$i]); 
                $pos = strpos($x, $word);
                if ($pos !== false) {
                    $result[] = $arr[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(search_dir(__DIR__, 'name'));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49424/discussion-on-answer-by-mrak-------).